# How do I make a div scrollable, without showing a nasty scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, css

My div is scrollable, using overflow: auto. But it shows a nasty scrollbar that doesn't match the style of my dialog, how do I either apply CSS to the scroll bar to attempt to fix it, or just remove it altogether?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2xEF/

Comment: Check out [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't reinvent the wheel! Scrollbars are there to make it easy for the user to scroll the page/content. Browser developers have taken care of all the necessary event handling, for instance, mouse wheel, page up/down, arrow up/down etc. If you program your own scrollbar, you have to take care of that, too. It won't be easy. And what you get in the end is a scrollbar that looks like like *your* page but not like *my* browser window.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- Make you own with some javascript magic
- Use `overflow: hidden`
- Hire someone to do it for you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers allow you to style the scrollbars. For instance, in Webkit-based browsers you can use the pseudo-elements. See [this blog](http://css-tricks.com/9130-custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) for more info. IE used to support changing the scroll bar color, but it no longer does.

If you want the same look in all browsers, I think your best bet is using some javascript UI component.